# Integrate of the primitive $\frac x{(2x-1)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

By using a suitable substitution or otherwise, find the value of
$$\int_1^3\frac x{(2x-1)^3}dx$$

This is what I've got so far:

let $$u=2x-1$$
$$dx=\frac{du}2$$

$x=\frac{u+1}2$
$$\int_1^3\frac{u+1}{4u^3}du$$

Integrating giving $$\left[\frac{-1}{4u}-\frac{1}{8u^2}\right]_1^3$$

giving $\frac{5}{18}$, but this is the wrong answer. I should be getting $0.32$.

Comment: When you do a change of variables, you need to change the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is mostly correct. When making the substitution $u = 2x - 1$ you mustn't forget to change the limit of integration. In this case $x = 1 \Rightarrow u = 1$ and $x = 3 \Rightarrow u = 5$. So we have

$$ \int_1^5 \dfrac{u + 1}{4u^3} \text{d}u$$

Can you solve this from here?

Comment: yes, thankyou. I forgot about the change in limits.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{3} \frac{x \ dx}{(2x-1)^{3}} &= \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{1}^{3} \frac{[ (2x-1) + 1] \ dx}{(2x-1)^{3}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{1}^{3} \frac{dx}{(2x-1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{1}^{3} \frac{ dx}{(2x-1)^{3}} \\
&= - \frac{1}{4} \left[ \frac{1}{2x-1} \right]_{1}^{3} - \frac{1}{8} \left[ \frac{1}{(2x-1)^{2}} \right]_{1}^{3} \\
&= \frac{8}{25}
\end{align}